# Batch goto keeps giving me the same output?

Tags: batch-file, goto

Here is the code I am using:

```
@echo off

:default
set /p cmd= "1 or 2"
if %cmd%=="1" goto one
if %cmd%=="2" goto two

:one
echo "1 worked"
goto default

:two
echo "2 worked"
goto default
```

However, the output I get is "1 worked" no matter what I put in. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe `%cmd%` is neither `"1"` or `"2"`. It will fall right through to `:one`.

Comment: Hint: run without echo off and watch what gets printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're ignoring the doublequotes. Unless the end user inputs `"1"` or `"2"` both sides of the comparison `==` will never match, and your code will always fail both `if` commands and continue on to `:one`. The fix is to ensure that both sides of the comparison are doublequoted.

This shows you how it should have worked, but please note that the end user can enter absolutely anything they want at the prompt, so you should technically perform some validation on that input before trying to use it. The best way is to instead use a more robust input method such as the `choice` command

This example uses your not recommended `Set /P` method:

```bat
@Echo Off

:default
Set "num="
Set /P "num=1 or 2"
If "%num%" == "2" GoTo two
If Not "%num%" == "1" GoTo default
Echo "1 worked"
GoTo default

:two
echo "2 worked"
GoTo default
```

*Note, I changed your variable name from `cmd`, as it is confusing to use command names as variable names.*

---

This uses the recommended `Choice` command instead:

```bat
@Echo Off

:default
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 12
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo two
Echo "1 worked"
GoTo default

:two
Echo "2 worked"
GoTo default
```

Alternatively you could use the error level as your `GoTo`:

```bat
@Echo Off

:default
"%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /C 12
GoTo Label%ErrorLevel% 2>NUL||GoTo default

:Label1
Echo "1 worked"
GoTo default

:Label2
Echo "2 worked"
GoTo default
```